# SQL Update field without unique index fields

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle

I have table without unique index tuples, lets say table has records

```
A->B->Status
A->C->Status
A->B->Status
A->B->Status 
A->C->Status
```

I am getting  first and second record, processing them. After then I want to update only these two records

how can I make this process possible at java application layer?

Since there is not any unique index tupples I cannot use update SQL with proper WHERE clause

Using 
Spring 3.XX
Oracle 11g

Comment: Why would you need an index to have a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think he mean a PK. So mmc, why you dont create a PK and solve a bad db design?

Comment: this table is transaction table and I donot want spend additonal "write DB" time by using PK

Comment: so you rather spend time solving bad design? db are design to handle writting PK. trying to optimize something engeneer have done lot of times isnt a wise use of resources. Good Luck

Comment: Changing of database design on live production systems is often impossible. It's usually too high risk and final decision is made by people who don't want to take any risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may try to use `ROWID` pseudocolumn.
For each row in the database, the `ROWID` pseudocolumn returns the address of the row. Oracle Database rowid values contain information necessary to locate a row:

- The data object number of the object
- The data block in the datafile in which the row resides
- The position of the row in the data block (first row is 0)
- The datafile in which the row resides (first file is 1). The file
  number    is relative to the tablespace.

Usually, a rowid value uniquely identifies a row in the database. However, rows in different tables that are stored together in the same cluster can have the same rowid.

```
SELECT ROWID, last_name  
   FROM employees
   WHERE department_id = 20;
```

The `rowid` for the row stays the same, even when the row migrates.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by using **updatable resultsets**. This feature relies on rowid to perform all modifications (delete/update/insert).

This is a excerpt highlighting the feature itself:

```
String sqlString = "SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Office " + 
        " FROM employees WHERE EmployeeID=1001";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlString);

        //Check the result set is an updatable result set
        int concurrency = rs.getConcurrency();
        if (concurrency == ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE) {
            rs.first();
            rs.updateString("Office", "HQ222");
            rs.updateRow();
        } else {
        System.out.println("ResultSet is not an updatable result set.");
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Here is a complete [example](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc/179).

Comment: No, that is not possible. However if you are worried about the performance, this solution above in fact is the fastest way of updating without pulling some serious hacks. Two years ago I spent a full day experimenting with different update technics to speed up a critical system. I settled with this, now the throughput is above 1.200 message/sec on a single server, including read / process (jms message) / update record to `processed`.